# How to list packages that have been installed from source in Linux?

Tags: linux, source

I usually use package managers like apt to install packages and then use dpkg to list the packages, that I have installed. Is there any way to get a similar list if I install from source? I saw an answer that states that, packages from sources are usually installed in /usr/local/bin and to look in there. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is for find all the files in to the system under investigation and exec command:

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

If the program return no package this file is probably from other source (or created by hand somehow). Same can be done with `apt-file`:

```
apt-file find /path/to/file
```

Be informed this process can take a lot of time.